# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' What is the problem?

Tags: python, pandas, opencv

```
def load_file():
  # Проходим циклом и загружаем все файлы из папок
  cat_files = []
  dog_files = []

  for i in (cat_name):
    df = cv2.VideoCapture(file_name_cat + i)
    frameCount = int(df.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    frameWidth = int(df.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    frameHeight = int(df.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    cat = np.empty((frameCount, frameHeight, frameWidth, 3), np.dtype('uint8'))
    fc = 0
    ret = True
    while (fc < frameCount  and ret): # The error is given here
      ret, cat[fc] = df.read()
      fc += 1
    cat_files.append(cat)
    
  for i in (dog_name):
    df = cv2.VideoCapture(file_name_dog + i)
    frameCount = int(df.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    frameWidth = int(df.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    frameHeight = int(df.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    dog = np.empty((frameCount, frameHeight, frameWidth, 3), np.dtype('uint8'))
    fc = 0
    ret = True
    while (fc < frameCount  and ret):
      ret, dog[fc] = df.read()
      fc += 1
    dog_files.append(dog)

  # Применяем функцию обработки для получения стройного массива
  cat_np = min_obs(cat_files)
  dog_np = min_obs(dog_files)

  # Возвращаем полученные массивы
  return cat_np, dog_np
```

Help me understand what the problem is? I am not very experienced yet and a lot of questions arise. For about 5 hours I tried to find a solution on the Internet. When I run it separately, everything works fine

The error text itself:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-140c0f9251eb> in <module>()
----> 1 cat_files, dog_files = load_file()

<ipython-input-5-2526f87de82a> in load_file()
     12     ret = True
     13     while (fc < frameCount  and ret):
---> 14       ret, cat[fc] = df.read()
     15       fc += 1
     16     cat_files.append(cat)

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Comment: The essence of this function is the return of a numpy array for subsequent submission to the neural network

Comment: Try replacing `ret, cat[fc] = df.read()` line with `pass` and describe what changes (if anything does)

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to close the question. I found what was the mistake. Some of my videos were broken. I removed them and everything worked